# NodeJS "The data will be lost if there is no listener when a Socket emits a 'data' event."

Tags: node.js, sockets, events

I am making a server in NodeJS using the Net module. It looks like the following:

```
const net = require('net');

server = new net.Server();
server.listen("{port: 80}");
server.on('connection', socket =>{
   socket.on("data", ()=>socket.write("Hey there!"));
});
```

The issue is that when I get two really close requests for the same client only the first gets served with a "Hey there!" response.

What I have read from the Net docs (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data) is that "If there is no listener when a Socket emits a 'data' event the data will be lost".
Am I loosing the second request because I am still writing the response to the first at `()=>socket.write("Hey there!")` when its event arrives?

If that's the case how do I avoid loosing 'data' events when I am serving others?